# Show child component when promise data is exists and also render the data in child omponent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implement search component for my application, parent component have the search text box and button. When the user provide some value i want to send the data to api and show the result in child component. I am bit confused where to call the api and also how to populate the data in child component. Also, initially my child component should not render in the parent component, when the search get some result then it can render. Please help me how to implement a search functionality in vue js 2.

Parent Component

```
<template>
  <div><h3> Search </h3></div>
  <div class="row">
    <form role="search">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" v-model="searchKey" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-on:click="getInputValue">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <result :searchdataShow='searchData'></result>
</template>
<script>
 import resultView from './result'
 export default {
  components: {
    'result': resultView
  },
 data () {
    return {
      searchKey: null,
      searchData: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
   getInputValue: function(e) {
     console.log(this.searchKey)
     if(this.searchKey && this.searchKey != null) {
       this.$http.get('url').then((response) => {
         console.log(response.data)
         this.searchData = response.data
       })
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Search Result component(child component)

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div class="row"><h3> Search Results</h3></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
   props: ['searchdataShow']
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable that keeps track of your ajax request, i usually call it `loading`, or `fetchedData`, depending on the context. Before the ajax call, set it to true, after the call, set it to false.

Once you have this variable working, you can then conditionally render the `result` component with `v-if`. I like to show a loading icon with the corresponding `v-else`.

Also your template doesn't seem to have a root element, which is required.

```
<template>
  <div><h3> Search </h3></div>
  <div class="row">
    <form role="search">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" v-model="searchKey" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-on:click="getInputValue">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <result v-if="!loading" :searchdataShow='searchData'></result>
  <div v-else>loading!!</div>
</template>
<script>
 import resultView from './result'
 export default {
  components: {
    'result': resultView
  },
 data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      searchKey: null,
      searchData: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
   getInputValue: function(e) {
     console.log(this.searchKey)
     this.loading = true;
     if(this.searchKey && this.searchKey != null) {
       this.$http.get('url').then((response) => {
         console.log(response.data)
         this.loading = false;
         this.searchData = response.data
       })
     }
   }
}
</script>
```